# JList: How to get a LineBorder "between" cells?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border, jlist

This is an example of a JList. I know how to set a border to the entire JList or the panel containing the JList. **My question is that how can we create line borders between the cells?`**

[image]

For example in the given picture the color of the line border between the first cell and the second is grey, while there is a white colored line border between all the other cells.

Please don't say that this is a `JComboBo`x or a `JTree` (because of the second element and its two children); even if it is not a `JLis`t, I want my `JList` to have similar `LineBorders` between the `cells`.

---

My web search led me to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html#getListCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JList,%20E,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) `interface`. Its method `getListCellRendererComponent` takes arguments like `E value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus`, while I want the `LineBorder` to appear *between all the cells* no matter what index they have and whether they are selected or not etc.

---

**EDIT:-**

[image]

The border is thicker in some places and fine in others.

Comment: you limited possible suggestions or answers by `Please don't say that this is` ---> look into docs and to change statndard borders, you want/have to to override isSelected and hasFocus to, rest is described in refused tutorials JComboBox, JList, JTable, JTree, this concept is similair for all those JComponents

Comment: how can we create line borders between the cells == search for AbstractBorder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive that with help of `ListCellRenderer`. Here is simple example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[]{"1","2","3"});
        list.setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
        add(list);
    }

    private ListCellRenderer<? super String> getRenderer() {
        return new DefaultListCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                    Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean cellHasFocus) {
                JLabel listCellRendererComponent = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,cellHasFocus);
                listCellRendererComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0,Color.BLACK));
                return listCellRendererComponent;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

Looks like:

[image]

Read more in [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

EDIT: Just change `LineBorder` to `MatteBorder`(have changed code and image).

Comment: Thank you.. actually this is very close to what I wanted. But what I want exactly is a line border just under the cell.  Because as you can see in the image, there is a border around the entire list, and there is line border between the cells. I have a border around a list, and then the border around the cells combines with that around the entire list and makes it thick and ugly. I am attaching a picture of my JList.